# How to set a Http Cookie from different trusted domains?

Tags: cookies, http-headers, cross-domain

On my local I have my app and my api on different hosts:

- app: https://front.shop.local/
- api: https://api.localhost/

I can set them on the same host, but this is by design to help to work on the cors.
My goal is to set the cookie on the domain `shop.local` from the response of the api.

I use `axios` with `{ withCredentials: true }` options.
When I send a login request to the api, here are my headers:

**Response headers**:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: https://front.shop.local
content-length: 168
content-type: application/json
date: Fri, 15 Jul 2022 17:36:41 GMT
server: Caddy
set-cookie: session_token=mytokennnn; Domain=.front.shop.local; Path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
vary: Origin
```

**Request headers**:

```
:authority: api.localhost
:method: POST
:path: /graphql
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr-FR;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,es;q=0.6,de;q=0.5,ru;q=0.4,la;q=0.3,mg;q=0.2
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 115
content-type: application/json
origin: https://front.shop.local
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://front.shop.local/
sec-ch-ua: ".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

In the cookie tab from the request from the POST on `https://api.localhost/graphql`:

[image]

I think a have set up everything to make it cors friendly as I have all the required headers and cookie settings.

I also tried to tweak the `Domain` value but none worked.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#invalid_domains

Comment: ok so http only cookie are encouraged, but we can't set it on any local domain ?